# Variance stabilising transformations

Tags: self-study, data-transformation, references

Can someone please point me to a textbook or lecture notes that explains what variance stabilising transformations are? I can only find bits and pieces on google.

I don't know a lot of statistics, but I know a decent amount of probability theory.

Comment: Our thread at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66001 might supply all you need to get started.

Answer (score 2):

There is a quite brief introduction to variance-stabilising transformations in Asymptotic Statistics by A.W. van der Vaart (2000). Many references to variance-stabilising transformations in textbooks/lecture notes will be in the context of the delta method.

Answer (score 1):

A nice, although short, introduction are given in these [lecture notes](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/asymp/lectures/asymp.pdf).

The basic idea in the setting of sample means, e.g. $X_i$ *iid* with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma(\mu)^2$, is to use CLT and delta method to find a function $g$ such that 
$$
n^{1/2}\left( g(\bar{X}_n) - g(\mu)\right) \overset{d}{\to}N(0, g'(\mu)^2\sigma(\mu)^2),
$$

and $g'(\mu)\sigma(\mu)=c$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$. This is just an example, of course. The idea is the same if you consider more general convergence in distribution and transformations $g$.

Comment: your statement $c \in \mathbb{R}$ should be qualified as also non-negative $c>0$. Negative variance makes no sense.

Comment: I have fixed a typo that caused the confusion @LucasRoberts.