# Are power law relations between means and standard deviations inherent in normally distributed data?

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, variance, mean

In a recent paper I submitted for publication I document a power law relation between the means and standard deviations of several time series. That is, when plotting the log of the means of each of these (stationary) series against the log of their respective standard deviations, you get a straight, positively sloped line (with non-zero y axis intercept).

When researching for this paper I scoured the internet for any possible statistical or mathematical explanation for this behavior, but found none, and could recall nothing from my own training in statistics that would explain this either. I discovered variance functions and Bartlett's identities along the way, but this still fell far short of explaining the relation I was documenting. The data I am dealing with are all normally distributed.

My paper was rejected, and one of the main grounds for rejection given by the editor was that the power law relation between means and standard deviations I had observed is "inherently true of more or less normally distributed sets of data".

Can someone please explain to me what the editor is talking about? Do power law relations trivially exist between the means and standard deviations of different normally distributed sets of data?

Edit: Some details on the data - Each data set is a stationary yearly time series. Number of observations in each series is the same. My logged plot of the means against their respective standard deviations follows below. In this graphic, the different shapes and colors of the points correspond to different commodity groups.

[image]

Comment: To restate this, why does the standard deviation increase (exponentially) with the mean? I think we would need to know more about your data. In my field, a positive relationship (not necessarily exponential on untransformed scale) is commonly seen because we deal with count data. This is of course bounded at zero and values close to zero are not uncommon. That of course implies that the data are NOT normally distributed, which you say it is in your case.

Comment: A relevant paper: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1111/biom.12728

Comment: The editorial comment is nonsensical as quoted here. First, there is no inherent relation between mean and SD of normal distributions. Second, as normal distributions in general can have positive, zero or negative means and SDs can't be negative, so also  proportionality is impossible as a general rule for that reason too.

Comment: I find it much easier to think of SD as a function of mean. Then one reference case is SD / mean = constant, which also implies thinking on a logarithmic scale. The ratio is widely if not better known as a the coefficient of variation. I call this a reference case because it leads to a wider idea of plotting log SD versus log mean, which (as above) doesn't make sense unless your data are all positive. I also have to echo @mkt-ReinstateMonica in wondering what you mean by normality of data. You may be doing some or even all of this.

Comment: There is a fairly massive literature both empirical and theoretical on variability as a function of level. Taylor's law is a good search phrase. The main locus is perhaps ecology.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you. That is exactly what I have been looking for for the past couple years. Judging by the wikipedia page on Taylor's law, it looks as though the cause of the empirical power law relation between level and variance is still an open question. In your opinion, is the cause a real feature of the data, or is it a mere artifact of the applied statistical/econometric method?

Comment: Here as often I am puzzled by the idea that econometric means something different from statistical, and why biometric, psychometric, ... don't get a mention. So, you must be an economist. More seriously, I am agnostic here. A power law is a pattern and sometimes you see it and sometimes you don't. Sometimes there is a plausible mechanism and sometimes there isn't. People have been fascinated and frustrated by these things over a century and more.

Comment: This kind of result is (easily) implied by observations made by [Frank Benford in 1938](https://www.jstor.org/stable/984802?seq=1).

Comment: @NickCox Apologies for my "economics-centric" handle on the semantics. Re: the matter at hand -- So, would it be fair to characterize the sorts of power law relations between level and variance observed by Taylor and others, and now me, as "empirical laws"? That is what researchers generally seem to call patterns in the data for which there is no clear statistical explanation. Another phrase they use sometimes is "stylized fact".

Comment: @whuber Benford's law does not appear to have yet been proposed in the literature as a potential explanation for Taylor's law. (Correct me if I'm wrong! I just became acquainted with this literature today, thanks to Nick Cox's comment.) Could you please elaborate? I am familiar with the basics of Benford's law but fail to see how it applies here.

Comment: All laws should be empirical, at least approximately, but the term is sometimes used in a slightly dismissive way if there isn't a good theoretical story. Most of the physics laws we learned in secondary school turn out be the same, I understand.

Comment: It's somewhat Heraclitean to regard variability as primary and level as secondary.

Comment: @NickCox *"...no clear theoretical explanation", I should say.

Comment: I like stories.  I have learned (I think from Peter Medawar) that people in Nobel-level labs are happy to ask each other what's your story for your results? The term is not pejorative as I use it, just informal.

Comment: @Ben Benford's Law is justified when a datset covers many orders of magnitude and variability is expressed (therefore) on a logarithmic scale.  You have noted not that there is any "power law" relation: your plot simply expresses homoscedasticity from this perspective.  I suspect that's what the reviewer might have been trying to say.

Comment: @whuber 1) The "log" in the plot above is the natural log, so the data span 3 orders of magnitude (10^2 to 10^4). Is that enough for Benford's law to apply? 2) I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the idea that Benford's law + homoskedasticity = power law correspondence between variances and means. There may be 100 bounty points in it for you if you can derive this result in an answer. 3) Why doesn't your explanation serve to explain Taylor's law?

Comment: Three orders of magnitude is excellent.  Taylor's Law appears to be much more specialized: it's related to spatial clustering.  At https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/66038/919 I describe a very general theory, used extensively in exploratory data analysis, that explains how power relationships between spread and level often are discovered in datasets.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for summarizing Emerson's explanation. I am still studying it, but it seems to say that *IFF* variances are stable across batches of data, then a power law relation can be expected between the level and spread of said batches. Is the "stable variance" part where homoscedasticity comes into play? Also, not clear where Benford fits into this. Bounty is expiring in a couple days. Seems like there's room here to expand upon your (already very nice) summary of Emerson, particularly as regards Benford.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear connection between Benford and Taylor's laws:
The nine Benford first digit probabilities are:
digit 1-30.1%, 2-17.6%, 3-12.5%, 4-9.7%, 5-7.9%, 6-6.7%, 7-5.8%, 8-5.1%, 9-4.6%.

Taylor's law as natural ln regression is: Ln (variance)=Ln (alpha) + (beta)* Ln (mean), where beta=slope and alpha a proportion constant.

Create a 4x9 table with rows (100,200,300,400) and columns (1 to 9, the Benford digits).
Populate the 4x9 table such as block (N=100, digit 1) value=30.1...(N=200, digit 1)value=60.2, N=300, value=90.3....
Calculate mean and variance for each first digit column (hint: mean for digit 1 will be 75.25, variance 1510.02...).
Calculate natural ln for each of the nine SUM mean and variance numbers.
Calculate regression of ln (variance) vs ln (mean) for the SUM digits, slope will be 1.9999 = ~ 2.0, R2 =0.9999 = ~ 1.0.

First digit probability predictions of the universal Benford law exactly predicts Taylor's law. Benford law explains the source of the beta slope parameter in Taylor's law (slope is outcome of multiple CONSTRAINTS related to collection of data such as random sampling, more than one order of magnitude in the set of data, naturally occurring systems with minimal human bias in the final tabulation of data, source of data from mathematical operations such as multiplication, which is very common in biological systems, also the positive skewed nature of the Benford probability distribution).
You will not find any published reference to above, it is my observation and attempt to help answer question asked...this is open for discussion and falsification or refinement.